# Atualizar valor de input com Bootstrap touchspin

Tags: jquery, input

Estou utilizado um **input** "quantidade" que multiplica o valor do **input** "valor unitário" e atualiza o **input** "valor total".
Até aqui funcionando tudo certo.

Então passei a utilizar o **bootstrap-touchspin** :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<input type="number" name="p_t11" id="P1103_QTDE" value="1" size="30" maxlength="4000">
    
<input type="text" name="p_t13" id="P1103_TOTAL" value="100,00" size="30" maxlength="4000">


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>

$("input[id='P1103_QTDE']").TouchSpin({
  min: 0,
  max: 10000000000,
  boostat: 5,
  forcestepdivisibility: "none",
  step: 1,
  maxboostedstep: 10,
  buttondown_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-xs btn-mob",
  buttonup_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-xs btn-mob",
  mousewheel: "true"
});
```

O **input** "total" não atualiza dinamicamente o valor na tela, mas salva o valor corretamente.
Como eu poderia atualizar o campo "valor total" dinamicamente clicando no "+" e "-" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deves rastrear o evento `change` que acontece no input a que o **bootstrap-touchspin** está associado.

Podes fazer assim:

```js
$("#P1103_QTDE").TouchSpin({
  min: 0,
  max: 10000000000,
  boostat: 5,
  forcestepdivisibility: "none",
  step: 1,
  maxboostedstep: 10,
  buttondown_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-xs btn-mob",
  buttonup_class: "btn btn-ciano btn-xs btn-mob",
  mousewheel: "true"
});

// daqui para baixo é o que precisas
$("#P1103_QTDE").on('change', function() {
    $('#P1103_TOTAL').val(($(this).val()*100).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/4.2.5/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" name="p_t11" id="P1103_QTDE" value="1" size="30" maxlength="4000">
    
<input type="text" name="p_t13" id="P1103_TOTAL" value="100,00" size="30" maxlength="4000">
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, funciona perfeitamente agora. Obrigado!

Comment: de nada @KimHanneman

Comment: Se necessário multiplicar por um valor variável do campo "valor unitário" #P1103_VALOR_UNITARIO, como seria?

Comment: @KimHanneman com essa amostra de código/imagem não sei onde está esse valor. Pelo código que colocaste a solução passa por isto